# Frequently crashing ununtu with unresponsive mouse and keyboard

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse

I am using Sony-Vaio laptop and my system specifications are Intel core i5 processor with Windows7 and Ubuntu 14.04 as dual-boot.
My problem is that my Laptop hangs frequently when I use Ubuntu even mouse and keyboard stops working, do I've to shut down my system to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**1) Restart ‘X’**

If the whole system comes to a freeze and does not accept any keyboard or mouse input, try to restart ‘X’ by pressing ‘Ctrl + Alt + Backspace‘. This will kill all processes and log you out. If this works, it should bring you to the login screen again.

**2) Use MagicSys Key to kill all processes**

If the crash is so serious that Ctrl + Alt + Backspace have no effect at all, try pressing the MagicSysKey ‘Alt + SysRq + K’ to kill all processes. The MagicSysKey is a set of keyboard combination that allow the users to perform various low level commands regardless of the system’s state using the SysRq key. In case you are wondering where the SysRq key is, in most keyboard configuration, it is found under the Print Screen button. In some laptop configuration, you might have to press the ‘Fn‘ button to access the SysRq key.

In short, press Alt + SysRq (possibly together with the ‘Fn‘ button) + K to kill all processes.

**3) If all the above fail…**

Try this MagicSysKey combination. It will sure work.

Press and hold Alt + SysRq, then one by one, press and release the following characters in the respective order: ‘R’ ‘E’ ‘I’ ‘S’ ‘U’ ‘B’. The system will perform a series of tasks and finally reboot the computer, safely.

This method should be used only if all other methods fail. If you have difficulty in remembering the character sequence, just remember the opposite of ‘BUSIER’.

if this is happening again and again after all above it's worth to try on reinstalling unity

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

also some of my friends who have a Nvidia graphic processor in their system,they recovered from this by installing **optimus** driver.if you have a Nvidia GPU then that may fix yours too.